# Alert box is not visible in firefox but Alert box is visible in chrome browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im using firefox v42 and selenium 2.47.0 .Manually alert box is visible in firefox browser but in automation is not visible.Alert box is also visible in chrome browser.I used firefox profile and also default browser both are not working .

```
    Webdriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("897PAN0301");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("86VPKg");
    driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("emailId"));

    email.clear();
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
    email.sendKeys("hello@gmai");
    WebElement agree = driver.findelement(By.id("agreement"))
    agree.click();
    alert.accept();//This alert is not working in automation but this alert is working manually in firefox v42 and also in chrome browser
```

Comment: What code did you write for it? Please add that in the question.

Comment: added please check it out

Comment: Hi, alert is not visible in the sense? alert is coming on after agree.click(); in execution? did you got any exception as if alert is not came this alert.accept(); will throw exception right? if there is no exception means it handles alerts. just give sleep between them to see alert box

Comment: What is an actual problem? I don't get it... You use `alert.accept()` to automatically handle alert, right? `Chrome` will ignore `Firefox.Profile` as it intended to work with `Firefox` only! So what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In chrome it accepts, that's true.
In IE and Firefox, it shows modal box exception, because of which the alert box gets disappears quickly and is not visible after alert.accept().
If u work with try catch block along with the given code, u can see that the screen will hold there after the alert box goes out.
For IE, u should use the following code:

```
options.UnexpectedAlertBehavior = InternetExplorerUnexpectedAlertBehavior.Accept;
```

during browser initialization,

but for firefox it is in the development phase, but u can try out with this:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.showModalDialog = window.openWindow;");

((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

in the firefox declaration, so that it automatically accept the ok button form the alert box.